# how to add tooltip to show price range change at handles when a customer adjusts the price range slider bar in ecommerce project?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, e-commerce, tooltip

am working on an e commerce project,and for filtering the results we have a price range slider bar,i want tooltip to appear in the bottom of the slider handles showing price range change when customers slide the slider to fix the price range.

code for my slider and the slider handles-

```
<div class=​"ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style=​"left:​ 0%;​ width:​   100%;​">​</div>​
<a class=​"ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href=​"#" style=​"left:​ 0%;​" data-original-title title>​</a>​
<a class=​"ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href=​"#" style=​"left:​ 100%;​">​</a>​
```

How do i add tooltip to this existing code?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you've tagged your question with Twitter-bootstrap, so I take it that you are using that in your project?

If so, can you add the rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" attributes to your  tags. E.g.

```
<a class=​"ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" rel="popover" data-placement="bottom" href=​"#" style=​"left:​ 0%;​" data-original-title title>​</a>​
```

Then on your jQuery, you can just select the item and add the details:

```
$("#sliderId").tooltip({
animation: true,
title: "Your title here"
});
```

List of attributes able to enable through bootstrap [here](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html)

Failing that, there is a nice slider available for free with tooltip already enabled: 
[Eyecon slider for boostrap](http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/)

Edited following comment:

Depending on how you are binding the data, it should be possible to pass the data in - I've copied in an example that I had inside a gridview.

```
<a class="photoPopover" href="#" rel="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<img src='<%#Eval("ImageURL")%>'/>"></a>
```

Comment: Ive already tried the eyecon slider ,it didnt work for me..in the above jquery u mentioned- i want values in the tooltip changing..but in the above jquery  if i enter a title,the tooltip would be displaying permanently that title..how do i make it dyanamic..would we write a function or how?

Comment: This really depends on how you are binding the data, I've edited my answer to give you an idea of how you might do this.